# Searching for "Item" in CSV file using java and apache commons CSV library

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I am trying to access the CSV file's data using the **Java** and A**pache commons CSV** library. 
I am stucked in a problem. 
The problem is:
"To Display the data of particular row if "Name" Header is equal to the "rahul". when I run the code nothing is printed out there."

The data in exportdata.csv file is :

- Name,Food,Phone
- rahul,Rice,9876416884
- ram,Egg,8437123456
- rohit,Burger,9814125755
- amit,chicken,8568934464

And my code is :

```
public class csvexample {

 public void readfile()
 {
    FileResource fr=new FileResource();
    CSVParser parser=fr.getCSVParser();
    for(CSVRecord record : parser)
    {

        String str=record.get("Name");
        System.out.println(str);

        if(str=="rahul")
        {
        System.out.print(record.get("Name") + "    ");
        System.out.print(record.get("Phone") + "    ");
        System.out.println(record.get("Food"));
        }          
    }
}
```

I think that the error is in the line **if(str=="rahul")** , I have checked that the program is not treating the str and "rahul" same when str="rahul" in First iteration of **for loop**.

Comment: I think that this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because they are 2 different String objects, even though they have the same characters.  Try `if ("rahul".equals(str))`

Comment: Thanxxxx alot......"Dbug"

Comment: I just tried the solution given by you....It worked fine....!!!   Thanxxx alot once again....!!!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

 public void readFile() {

    String csvFile = "exportdata.csv";
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] str = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            String name = str[0];

            if(name.equals("rahul")){
                System.out.print("Name: " + str[0]);
                System.out.print(" Food: " + str[1]);
                System.out.println(" Phone: " + str[2]);
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanxxx...alot....!!!  I am just going to try it and ...Let you know If I face any difficulty.